# How high could Ingenuity fly?

Tags: mars, atmosphere, aerodynamics, ingenuity

On its 59th flight, Ingenuity achieved a height of 20 meters - twice as high as its maximum height during the original 5 flights that it was designed and expected to last for.  In the scheduled 61st flight, the plan is for it to climb 24 meters.

It seems reasonable that they will continue pushing these boundaries as long as Ingenuity lasts.  **How high could it climb?**

I would assume that it is limited by:

1. The time/power it takes to ascend
2. Different air properties, such as lower pressure, at higher altitudes
3. Software not being able to handle the ground being so far away (this has been the case in the past for Ingenuity, [requiring a software upgrade to go past 15 meters](https://www.nasa.gov/solar-system/nasa-extends-ingenuity-helicopter-mission/))

Which of these reasons, or others, would ultimately limit the helicopter?  And at roughly what height would this limit take effect?

Comment: Isn't "how high can Ingenuity fly" what they're trying to determine with this series of experiments?

Comment: Yes, but I do not feel as if that makes the question invalid - there is surely some upper limit that can be estimated beforehand.

Comment: On paper spec the alt was 33ft, but in subsequent flights on mars theyve managed almost 66ft

Comment: The answer provided is predicated on safe landing on available battery power. What if this limit were removed and the question becomes about absolute aerodynamics performance envelope? At 100% power how high could it go before it would just stop going up?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

While Ingenuity would theoretically eventually hit a "service ceiling" above which the atmosphere is no longer dense enough to provided a TWR (Thrust-Weight-Ratio) of above 1, I suspect the major limit is Ingenuity's battery life/flight endurance.

According to the specifications from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingenuity_(helicopter)), the critical numbers are:

> Maximum range, radio: 1000m
>
> Flight time: Up to 167 seconds per flight
>
> Maximum possible speed: Vertical: 3 m/s

So, disregarding acceleration and assuming that the flight profile is a straight ascent followed by a (controlled) descent, you would be able to budget 83.5 seconds to ascending which would reach a height of around 250 meters (double that if a crash-landing is acceptable).

To validate that atmospheric pressure reduction with altitude plays no significant role at this scale, the following formula can be used:

Barometric formula for pressure at height h:

$$P(h) = P_0 \times \left(1 - \frac{L \times h}{T_0}\right)^{\frac{g \times M}{R \times L}}$$

Variables:

- $P(h)$ is the pressure at height h
- $P0$ is the pressure at sea level (or surface level in the case of Mars)
- $L$ is the temperature lapse rate
- $h$is the height above sea level
- $T0$ is the temperature at sea level
- $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity
- $M$ is the molar mass of the planet's air
- $R$ is the universal gas constant

Constants for Mars:

- $P0$ = 640 Pa (Pressure at surface)
- $L$ = -0.0045 K/m (Temperature lapse rate)
- $T0$ = 210 K (Temperature at surface)
- $g$ = 3.72076 m/s^2 (Acceleration due to gravity)
- $M$ = 0.04334 kg/mol (Molar mass of Mars' air)
- $R$ = 8.314 J/(mol·K) (Universal gas constant)

Evaluating for our 250-meter flight, we get about a 2% drop in pressure, which is negligible.

As for software, while I don't know exactly what Ingenuity runs, I don't see a reason why it couldn't be modified to enable flight to much higher altitudes. Yes, it relies on optical flow (camera sees ground) to stabilize, but (as someone who has experience building and flying drones), there shouldn't be any reason why an IMU-only approach couldn't be used if it is so high that the camera can no longer properly see the ground (although it would probably not land in exactly the same spot as where it took off).

Comment: This is comprehensive and convincing!  Thanks :)

Comment: So the molar mass makes the temperarure lapse rate work for the Mars calculation? I guess that would be true for Earth calculations also, I just hadn't thought about it before.

Comment: could rotor auto-rotation be used for an unpowered descent for most of downward travel in order to conserve battery for final landing?

Comment: "you would be able to budget 83.5 seconds to ascending" – Well, technically, the question didn't require that the aircraft land intact …

Comment: @JörgWMittag I.e. "How high could Ingenuity's *last* flight be?"

Comment: I think the density is the key factor, not pressure. However, the conclusion is the same -- the practical maximum altitude constraint is battery life (and the requirement to land safely).

Comment: @BradV Autorotation? *Maybe*, but I'm skeptical. Ingenuity's props are very unlike traditional heli props being very lightweight and having much less inertia. They're also a significant fraction of the whole drone's mass and need to spin very quickly to lift in the thin atmo. Maybe an absolutely last second "flare" could make the landing survivable, but again, I'm skeptical.

Comment: @Dragongeek "having much less inertia" and "being a significant fraction of the whole drone's mass" are contradictory claims imho

Comment: @jkztd Inertia is largely dependent on blade geometry, and the blades on ingenuity have far more of their mass (and surface area) located near the shaft compared to a traditional heli-blade at a similar scale which has a rather even mass-distribution across it's length. I think this would have a negative effect on autorotation compared to normal blades at the same scale.

Comment: @Dragongeek this is a good point, maybe the blades' variable pitch aoa range is just enough for cyclic and yaw control while under powered flight. Indeed the blades are so twisted from root to tip  that they may be too draggy to allow auto-rotation in the first place.